# What's the right way to set Linux kernel runtime parameters?

Tags: linux, kernel, parameter, sysctl

What's the prescribed way to set Linux kernel runtime parameters? I've seen sometimes that people will set these in files such as `/etc/rc.local`.

Is this really the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sysctl` to set some of the kernel parameters, specifically the ones under `/proc/sys`. These can be set in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` or added to a single file (the preferred method on some distro's such as Fedora) in the directory `/etc/sysctl.d`. On distros that have this directory it's meant for customization's.

*excerpt from sysctl's man page*

```
   sysctl - configure kernel parameters at runtime
```

#### Example

You can get a partial list of what kernel parameters are currently set using this command:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | head -5
abi.vsyscall32 = 1
debug.exception-trace = 1
debug.kprobes-optimization = 1
dev.cdrom.autoclose = 1
dev.cdrom.autoeject = 0
```

### Making a change

#### /etc/sysctl.conf

Simply add rules to the file `sysctl.conf`.

```
# sysctl.conf sample
#
kernel.domainname = example.com
; this one has a space which will be written to the sysctl!
kernel.modprobe = /sbin/mod probe
```

You can also use the `sysctl.conf` command line to make edits to this file without having to edit it directly.

```
$ sysctl -w kernel.domainname="example.com"
```

After making any changes be sure to make them active.

```
$ sysctl -p
```

#### /etc/sysctl.d

To add your override of this parameter simply put it in a file named similarly to the files that are already present in the `/etc/sysctl.d` directory.

```
$ ls -l /etc/sysctl.d
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77 Jul 16  2012 10-console-messages.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  490 Jul 16  2012 10-ipv6-privacy.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  726 Jul 16  2012 10-kernel-hardening.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1184 Jul 16  2012 10-magic-sysrq.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  509 Jul 16  2012 10-network-security.conf
...
```

In a file named something like `99-myparam.conf`.

```
$ more 10-console-messages.conf 

# the following stops low-level messages on console
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
```

Where the name of the parameter is on the left, and it's corresponding value is on the right.

See `sysctl`'s man page for more details.

Comment: Which distributions/init systems use `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d`?

Comment: @Gilles At the very least, systemd 207+ does not read from `sysctl.conf` any more, it requires `sysctl.d`.

Comment: @Gilles - Fedora is one. I have both those on my F19 system.

Comment: @Gilles - I've made mention of this difference. I wasn't aware that it wasn't this case on other distros.